# How write input with Razor in javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How Writre Input By Razor In Javascript?

`@Html.TextBox("Name",null,new{@class="form-control"})`

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: `var myTextBox = '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="Name"/>';`

Comment: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-textbox-textboxfor first google link

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Write a div with a id, in which you want your HTML

Eg:

```
<div id="nameDiv"></div>
```

Then in your script, write this:

```
<script>
    var nameDivInput= '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"/>';
    document.getElementById("nameDiv").append(nameDivInput);
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write Razor in JavaScript because Razor is server-side and JavaScript is client-side.